# Prime from mirror concatenation of first primes

Tags: prime-numbers

The mirror concatenation of the first 1, 6 and 8 prime numbers with no primes being reversed is a prime ! i.e. 131175323571113 and 19171311753235711131719 are prime numbers! (beautiful primes!). After these I couldn't find other primes with such form up to the first 2500 primes(!). Does there exist prime number of such form after these three ?